# Failed to Integrate daisyUI (plugin for TailwindCSS) with Angular

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, daisyui

Hi guys here I want to integrate my Angular (12) with daisyUI (2.15.0). Everything goes right when I integrated the Angular with TailwindCSS (2.2.19), and also there's no problem with daisyUI installation. However, when I registered the daisyUI plugin into *tailwind.config.js*, the problem begin. Here is my *tailwind.config.js* :

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,ts}"],
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")], //everything goes right without this
};
```

The problem begin when I put the `require("daisyui")`. My Tailwind CSS Intellisense showed an error message:

> Tailwind CSS: :4:1: Variant cannot be generated because
> selector contains no classes.

This problem caused my Angular can't be used anymore. Anyway I followed the instruction from this source: https://daisyui.com/docs/install/

Comment: I have the same issue and am still looking for a solution. Have you seen this https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1833? This did not solve my problem but believe it may surround what is being discussed. I will keep trying to work out how to fix...

Answer (score 7):

Update `TailwindCSS` from version 2 to 3.

`npm install tailwindcss@3`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,ts}"],
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
   plugins: [require(getDaisyUI())],
};
function getDaisyUI() {
  return "daisyui";
}
```

Same things happened with me while using tailgrids so I extraced this to a function in global scope.

```
function getDaisyUI() {
  return "daisyui";
```

like this and it solved it for me.

Comment: Please add a little textual explanation to your answer: Why and how does it work and what is the difference to the other answer given?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the two bolded lines in `.eslintrc.cjs` will work

.eslintrc.cjs:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
// this line--------
    node: true,
//----------
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 'latest', sourceType: 'module' },
  settings: { react: { version: '18.2' } },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
    'warn',
    { allowConstantExport: true },
  ],
// this line----------
  "react/prop-types": "off"
// --------------
  },
}
```